# Unable to use newly published Angular Library

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-library

I am new to publishing Angular libraries and this is my first humble attempt to publish a lib to NPM called wps-ng https://www.npmjs.com/package/wps-ng.

My Public Api file looks like https://github.com/singkara/wps-js-ng/blob/library_test/projects/wps-ng/src/public-api.ts where I have exported the following:

```js
export * from './lib/wps-ng.service';
export * from './lib/wps-ng.component';
export * from './lib/wps-ng.module';
```

...

However, when I do npm install wps-ng in a 3rd party Angular 9 application, it fails with the error:

```
TS2307: Cannot find module 'wps-ng' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Although, I am able to use this same library (from the dist folder) in the same project as that of the library itself but not from third party application (from node_modules folder).

Any thoughts on why this could happen?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think you might be missing the `module` property in your lib's `package.json` file. It needs to point to the compiled js version of your `public_api.ts` file.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I tried adding the module tag in package.json and pointed it to src/public_api.ts. However, it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out the issue finally,
What I did wrong was, I published the library by running the command `npm publish` in the library folder.

However, the correct way to do this is by running the following commands:

1. ng build
2. cd dist
3. cd `your library name`
4. npm pack
5. npm publish

Comment: Do you also have to remove the /dist from .gitignore?